# Como resolver o erro Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: react, nginx

estou com o seguinte problema estou recebendo um erro de Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' em minha aplicação react.

estou utilizando o single-spa este erro esta acontecendo na aplicação do root-config.
esta aplicação esta utilizando nginx com a seguinte configuração
server
{
listen 9001;
listen [::]:9001;
location / {
root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
index  index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/ index.html =400;
}
}

meu container esta sendo buildada da aplicação react e copiando os arquivos index.html, app.js e app.js.map para a pasta /usr/share/nginx/html.

meu codigo em desenvolvimento funciona muito bem. Porem em produção ele apresenta problemas. pois quando a aplicação é buildada e alocada em um container em produção a utl do container é parecida com https://dominio/rotacontainer/neste ponto viriam as rotas da aplicação.
por ser parte de um mfe e sendo root cada um dos fontes possuem "rotacontainer" diferentes, porem o root não executa e gera o erro Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'.
uma coisa que eu verifiquei é que em meu container os arquivos index.html, app.js e app.js.map ficam com as seguintes permissões -rw-r--r-- em outras aplicações que executo não ficam assim.

Comment: da uma olhada em [Como fazer uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Sua pergunta está organizada de um jeito confuso, pois mescla diversas informações sobre diferentes coisas. 

Seria interesante que tu pudesse isolar mais a origem desse problema antes de postar a pergunta.

Answer (score -2):

Fala man, boa tarde, normalmente esse erro está relacionado com erro na sintaxe do projeto (Erro gerado por digitar algo de forma errada), se você estiver somente consumindo uma API, pode ser que o erro esteja na forma que você a chamou ou utilizou, no caso de você está fazendo também o seu backend fica um pouco mais complicado, por que o erro pode está tanto na parte de chamar a api, quanto na forma que você trata ela no seu back, então rever o seu código por partes talvez ajude a concertar esse erro.